# Is there a way to print configuration parameters?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, erl

I have configured two parameters.

```
inet_dist_listen_min = X
inet_dist_listen_max = Y
```

in the config file and I copied it the config file in the place it should be.
Is there a way to know that either RabbitMQ or ERL receive the right parameter?

Thanks.

Note: Eventually I did it using a sniffer (saw the TCP port in the packet) and knew it received it,
but is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 2):

for rabbitmq

```
rabbitmqctl environment
```

for erlang env params

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_all_env(kernel).'
```

and

```
epmd -names
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html :

`rabbitmqctl list_parameters {-p vhost}`

Isn't it that you need?