# Bad CONNECT when trying to subscribe to message queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, stompjs

I'm completely new to RabbitMQ and now I'm looking for a configuration error. The client doesn't receive any messages from RabbitMQ and I debugged it as far as possible.

**Frontend messages:**

Message 1:

```
CONNECT
login:frontend_listener
passcode:xxx
accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
heart-beat:20000,0
```

Message 2:

```
ERROR
message:Bad CONNECT
content-type:text/plain
version:1.0,1.1,1.2
content-length:30

Virtual host '/' access denied
```

There are two vHosts: `/` and `someVhost` and there are different users like `frontend_listener`. Now I [found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22449124/426227) to access the log file.

**RabbitMQ log file:**

```
2020-02-11 15:50:53.579 [warning] <0.798.0> STOMP login failed for user "frontend_listener"
2020-02-11 15:50:53.579 [error] <0.798.0> STOMP error frame sent:
Message: "Bad CONNECT"
Detail: "Access refused for user 'frontend_listener'\n"
Server private detail: none
...
2020-02-11 15:51:25.349 [info] <0.850.0> Creating user 'frontend_listener'
2020-02-11 15:51:30.374 [info] <0.857.0> Setting permissions for 'frontend_listener' in 'someVhost' to '$', '$', 'client-notification.*'
2020-02-11 15:51:54.980 [warning] <0.867.0> STOMP login failed - not_allowed (vhost access not allowed)~n
2020-02-11 15:51:54.980 [error] <0.867.0> STOMP error frame sent:
Message: "Bad CONNECT"
Detail: "Virtual host '/' access denied"
Server private detail: none
2020-02-11 15:52:56.427 [warning] <0.875.0> STOMP login failed - not_allowed (vhost access not allowed)~n
```

It reads like the permissions are wrong. Can someone help me out interpreting that correctly?

I try to read it: User `frontend_listener` wants to access the vHost `/`, but it hasn't sufficient permissions (don't know what `$` here mean other than a part of regular expression). The thing is, that I don't know if that is the correct vHost. How do I find out the URL of each vHost?

I'm asking this because I believe that the mapping to the vHost is wrong or something is missing.

**Edit:**

After adding `host: 'someVhost'` to my `stomp-config.ts` I was able to subscribe to the queues. Now I get the following error in the log:

```
2020-02-12 16:32:25.913 [error] <0.5159.1> Channel error on connection <0.5149.1> (127.0.0.1:58136 -> 127.0.0.1:15674, vhost: 'someVhost', user: 'frontend_listener'), channel 1:
operation basic.consume caused a channel exception access_refused: access to queue 'stomp-subscription-SZ3-PO1-PbZroPol-WXSQw' in vhost 'someVhost' refused for user 'frontend_listener'
2020-02-12 16:32:26.022 [error] <0.5145.1> STOMP error frame sent:
Message: access_refused
```

On the frontend I don't get a message or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also pass host information in the STOMP `CONNECT` frame..

this is what the specifications says and clients MUST set this header

> host : The name of a virtual host that the client wishes to connect to. It is recommended clients set this to the host name that the socket was established against, or to any name of their choosing. If this header does not match a known virtual host, servers supporting virtual hosting MAY select a default virtual host or reject the connection.

So this is how your CONNET frame should look

```
CONNECT
login:frontend_listener
passcode:xxx
accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
host: someVhost
heart-beat:20000,0
```

Comment: The spec can be found here https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#CONNECT_or_STOMP_Frame & other helpful link is https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that I'm one step further. What I don't understand that the old configuration does work on another instance (without `host` configuration). Now I'm getting a *access_refused* message. Could you also help with this?

Comment: So the reason for working without the host configuration on another instance can be either of the two . 1. The instance has a single host named someVhost or 2. The host by the name of someVhost is the default host.

Comment: Also make sure that the user fontend_listener has the permission  "configure", "write" and "read" on the host someVhost

Comment: The permission currently is `'$', '$', 'client-notification.*'` for "configure", "write" and "read". If I only want to grant read access, wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: Now I set the permissions to `*` for all and it would work that way. Both instances have two vhosts so there must be a configuration difference. Do you know how I can set the default host?

Comment: Yes the default vhost can be defined in the file  rabbitmq.conf by default it is default_vhost = /

Comment: Further read https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-items

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I printed the config with `rabbitmqctl environment` and I get `{default_vhost,<<"/">>},` on the working environment. Is there some config elsewhere?

Comment: Never mind. Seems that is a docker misconfiguration issue.